# What kind of supervision do new captains get on their first flight?

Tags: faa-regulations

Is there any special consideration for the first flight as a captain? I mean, the first officer gets promoted to captain, does his/her first flight gets supervised by any special way?

PS: I'm tagging this question as faa-regulation, not so sure if it is correct.. please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a new captain is done with schoolhouse training (classroom and simulator) they will fly on-line as a captain and will have a training captain in the right seat.  After some number of flights (for me it was a 4-day pairing) you will be joined by a check airman in the jumpseat and have a line check.

Once you pass the line check if you are a first time captain you are a high minimums captain for your first 100 hours and then a normal captain. During high mins time you are subject to a few restrictions in approaches you can fly. All the flying after the line check is with normal (low time) first officers.

Comment: "you will be joined by a check airman in the jumpseat and have a line check" I'm sorry, didn't get that.. could you explain a little bit please?

Comment: @mendieta you'll fly at least one leg with a the new captain in the left seat, a training captain in the right seat and a check airmen in the jumpseat (a third seat in the cockpit).  The line check is a specific kind of checking event where the check airman observes a crew during a normal flight and evaluates the pilots.  In this case the evaluation is to release the new captain to the line to fly with normal first officers.  A captain will get a line check once a year.